# vTiger webservice update operation

Tags: api, vtiger

im trying to do an update operation from angular 2 but i dont know how to pass the element parameter

in the vtigercrm.log i see DEBUG webservice -

```
array ('element' => NULL)
```

which leads to this

```
"error": {
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Permission to perform the operation is denied for id",
```

i tryied passing the following object as a JSON

```
{
"subject":"test2",
"assigned_user_id":"19x1",
"date_start":"2016-11-15",
"time_start":"12:00:00",
"due_date":"2016-11-15",
"time_end":"14:00:00",
"recurringtype":"",
"duration_hours":"2",
"duration_minutes":"0",
"parent_id":"",
"eventstatus":"Planned",
"sendnotification":"0",
"activitytype":"Call",
"location":"",
"createdtime":"2016-11-15 11:31:19",
"modifiedtime":"2016-11-15 11:31:19",
"taskpriority":"",
"notime":"0",
"visibility":"Public",
"modifiedby":"19x1",
"description":"",
"reminder_time":"",
"contact_id":"",
"latitud":"",
"longitud":"",
"id":"18x22029"
}
```

the same thing as encodeURI and encodeURIComponent but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, and I found a subtle difference in the JSON.  When a result was returned, the json object is the first element in an array.  But for sending, it needs to be just the object, not an array.

```html
<?php

//decode the json encode response from the server.
$jsonResponse = json_decode( $response->getBody(), true );

//Get first array element for sending back with update   
$objectJson = json_encode($jsonResponse[ 'result' ][0]);
    
?>
```

Whenever I tried sending the original response, I received an error: {"success":false,"error":{"code":"ACCESS_DENIED","message":"Permission to perform the operation is denied for id"}}

Answer (score 0):

This error message can be due to:

1. Object ID not mentionned/correct in the JSON objet that you send as the parameter "element"
2. Vtiger Session ID not sent/correct in the parameter "sessionName"

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044166/webservice-php-vtiger-update-query-string-php-curl-post/41353117#41353117) an example (in PHP) of how to pass the object to perform an update